# When are two CFG's different?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

If two CFG's differ only in what names they use for their non-terminals, are they different?

For example, are these CFG's different:
$$\begin{align*}
S &\to A  \\
A &\to a \end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
S &\to B  \\
B &\to a
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Depends on your definition of "different", obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Two grammars $G_1 = \langle \Sigma, V_1, S_1, P_1 \rangle$ and $G_2 = \langle \Sigma, V_2, S_2, P_2 \rangle$ are

- *[weakly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(formal_languages))* if $L(G_1) = L_(G_2)$
- *strongly equivalent* if $L(G_1) = L_(G_2)$ and for every string $w$ in the language, the minimal left-most derivations of $w$ in $G_1$ and the minimal left-most derivations of $w$ in $G_2$ are exactly the same in number, and can be put in one-to-one corresponce (note that the number of derivation trees must be the same in number if the grammars are ambiguous, i.e. they must be ambiguous "in the same way")

Example:

$G_1 = S \to A; A \to 1B; A\to 1; B\to 0A$; we have $L(G_1) = \{ (10)^*1 \}$

$G_2 = S \to B; B \to A1; B\to 1; A\to B0$; we have $L(G_2) = \{ 1(01)^* \}$

- *isomorphic* if there is a bijection $\phi : V_1 \to V_2$ such that $\phi(S_1) = S_2$ and $\phi(P_1) = P_2$ (after extending $\phi$ to productions and set of productions in the natural way).

Note that weakly equivalence is undecidable, while strongly equivalence (and ismorphism) are decidable.

As a final remark I think that - in most formal language contexts - it would be fine to say that the grammars in your question *are the same grammar* :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Different, but equivalent** (in a certain sense).

Usually a CFG is defined as a tuple $(N, T, S, P)$ where $N$ and $T$ are the sets of non-terminals, $S \in N$, and $P$ is the set of productions. Using this definition, the two grammars would be necessarily different since you have different sets of non-terminals (and different productions).

Nevertheless, you could also say the two CFGs are *equivalent* in the sense that the two are equal up to renaming the non-terminals. This is a stronger equivalence than, for instance, simply generating the same language.

As an aside, note an equivalence based on renaming the terminal symbols (or even both terminals and non-terminals) is also conceivable.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, the two grammars are different. On the other hand, they obviously generate the same language and thus they are *equivalent*.

But beyond equivalence they are also structurally equal. This *equality up to renaming symbols* is probably best captured by the concept of *isomorphism*.